# django simplejson [] is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-views, simplejson

in my view, why does this work:

```
results = []
results.append({'status':1})
results.append({'bookmarks':[]})
simplejson.dumps(results)
# produces: []
```

and this doesn't:

```
from myapp.models import Bookmark
results = []
results.append({'status':1})
results.append({'bookmarks':Bookmark.objects.all()})
# fails with exception saying: [] is not JSON serializable
```

completely stack trace follows

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/Ishaq/Projects/github/bookmarks/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Ishaq/Projects/github/bookmarks/bookmarks/views.py" in index
  9.   return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(Bookmark.objects.all()), mimetype='application/json');
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py" in dumps
  231.         return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in encode
  201.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in iterencode
  264.         return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py" in default
  178.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Exception Type: TypeError at /conferences/
Exception Value: [] is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: `simplejson.dumps(list(Bookmark.objects.all()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was waiting for Burhan Khalid to turn his comment into an answer, but since he hasn't, I would.

using `simplejson.dumps(list(Bookmark.objects.all()))` made it work

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `simplejson` for serialize django objects, use s[erialization provided by django.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-data)

With reference form the link, you can do:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", Bookmark.objects.all())
```

Comment: actually i have to make a custom json object instead dumping just the model. and the docs were unclear on this.

Comment: @ishaq, But your question does not say so. You are trying to serialize `Bookmark.objects.all()`.

Comment: @Rohan is serialize is much faster than json or there is any specific reason for that